# Conditions of Separating a Value in Spatial Dimensions

Tags: heat, engineering-general

In most of my engineering experience whenever we work in multiple dimensions we can almost always use superposition to get a specific property or quantity in x,y, and z. In these cases, we have always used the square root of the sum of x,y, and z to get the total magnitude.

When learning PDE's I noticed that heat does not follow this property (via superposition of Poisson equation in a rectangle). And that the magnitude of heat is simply the sum of net heat in x,y, and z (instead of the sqrt(sum(components)).
[image]

This makes sense as temperature is a scalar quantity but I was just wondering if anyone had any additional insights into when and how we know how to spatially superimpose a property or quantity.